# Blob is not writeable

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

When I am trying to take azure db backup using azure `rm command` (New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport), I am facing the below issue

```
Error encountered during the service operation. Blob https://XXXXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/XXXXX-container/ABC.bacpacklj1234klj12l3k4jl2k34jl2k3j4lk23j4l12k34jlk23j4lk23lk4j234A8i3t1GAs4Tvx2wjQRf7nTi/fM0+v7o7SWuUTU6WpRwO2SM0w== is not writeable. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

But by using the same container I am able to take backup of web app using New-AzureRmWebAppBackup command.

> Note: The public access level of the contianer is blob. I also tried for container.

Please let me know any have a solution for this issue.

Comment: I am guessing that it has something to do with special characters (`+`, `/`. `=`) in the blob name. Can you try by escaping the special characters (essentially URL encoding the blob name)?

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for your comments. Even I am getting the same error when I tried without special characters.

Comment: Can you try to run the Cmdlet with `-Debug` switch? Usually you should get more information in that case which would help you in finding the problem.

Comment: -Debug is not recognized with that command.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the credentials to your command, try the following syntax of the command is as follows:

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database01" -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" -StorageKey "StorageKey01" -StorageUri "http://account01.blob.core.contoso.net/bacpacs/database01.bacpac" -AdministratorLogin "User" -AdministratorLoginPassword "secure password"
ResourceGroupName          : RG01
ServerName                 : Server01
DatabaseName               : Database01
StorageKeyType             : StorageAccessKey
StorageKey                 : 
StorageUri                 : http://account01.blob.core.contoso.net/bacpacs/database01.bacpac
AdministratorLogin         : User
AdministratorLoginPassword : 
AuthenticationType         : None
OperationStatusLink        : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/resource01/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/server01/databases/database01/importExportOperationResults/00000000-00
                             0-0000-0000-000000000000?api-version=2014-04-01
Status                     : InProgress
ErrorMessage               :
```

This should fix your issue.Full syntax of the command can be found here:**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabaseexport?view=azurermps-5.7.0**

Comment: $azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "XXXXXX" -AsPlainText -Force 

$storageAccountKey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "XXXX" -Name "XXXX"

$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -Debug -AdministratorLogin "XXXXXXX" `
-AdministratorLoginPassword $azurePassword `
-DatabaseName "dbName" `
-ResourceGroupName "XXXX" `
-ServerName "DBServer" `
-StorageKey $storageAccountKey[0].Value `
-StorageKeyType "SharedAccess" `
-StorageUri "https://XXXX.blob.core.windows.net/backup/dbName_bkp.bacpac"

Comment: Try to remove/edit any sensitive information such as password or sensitive information. I'll follow up with this post tomorrow

Comment: Hi Adam. Above is the command I have tried. Please let me know anything I have missed out.

Comment: Can you please file a support request @
https://aka.ms/azsupt? and send me the ticket number, If you do not have access to a support plan, please reach out @ AZCommunity[AT]microsoft.com with a link to this Doc/Issue as well as your subscription ID and we can help get the support ticket opened for this issue.
I'll follow up on it to ensure your issue gets resolved.

Comment: Thanks Adam. My Current DB is in S0 pricing tier. So I took the db scripts and created a new DB with S2 pricing tier. And I tried the same Azure RM commands. It got worked. I don't know whether the issue with pricing tier or with my DB. But I am able to take backup.