# AzureSQL backup automation using powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I am writing a code for take the Azure SQL backup on Blob storage using powershell script.
 When I ran the script it is showing in progress but after some time when I checked in blob container im not able to see any .bacpac(Backup) file.
when I tried to ran again after some time the code some time it will show error like below 
[image]

but after some time when I running my code again it is executing successfully and status will shows "in progress". but when Im checking under the blob container there will be no file.
please find script on below-

```
$subscriptionId = "*****"
$serverAdmin = '****'
$serverPassword = '****'
$securePassword    = ConvertTo-SecureString $serverPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$creds           = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($serverAdmin, $securePassword)
$DatabaseName ='*****'
$ResourceGroupName='*****'
$ServerName='*****'

# Generate a unique filename for the BACPAC
$bacpacFilename = $DatabaseName + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".bacpac"

# Storage account info for the BACPAC
$BaseStorageUri = "https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/*****"
$BacpacUri = $BaseStorageUri + $bacpacFilename
$StorageKeytype = "StorageAccessKey"
$StorageKey = "*****"

New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
   -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
   -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password
```

Comment: Could you check the status with `Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus`? see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-powershell. When you see `Status: Succeeded` the export is complete

Comment: Thanks @JoyWang for valuable comment. I tried earlier this but im getting BadRequest error. please find the error - Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus : BadRequest: The ImportExport operation with Request Id '5d95702e-04f6-4e83-8e0d-65f64788168e' failed due to 'Error encountered during the service operation. Blob https://****.blob.core.windows.net/*** is not writeable. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: Did see this blob:[Blob is not writeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809232/blob-is-not-writeable)?

Answer (score 0):

I have a question, please look at your code:
[image]

Why these code `-DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri`  are `String` ?

Then executing `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` will definitely get an error. You can see this document: [New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabaseexport?view=azurermps-5.7.0).

And  about the another error:

```
Error encountered during the service operation. Blob https://****.blob.core.windows.net/*** is not writeable. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
```

I think you can see this blob as a reference: [Blob is not writeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809232/blob-is-not-writeable). This blob has the same error like you:

```
Error encountered during the service operation. Blob https://XXXXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/XXXXX-container/ABC.bacpacklj1234klj12l3k4jl2k34jl2k3j4lk23j4l12k34jlk23j4lk23lk4j234A8i3t1GAs4Tvx2wjQRf7nTi/fM0+v7o7SWuUTU6WpRwO2SM0w== is not writeable. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

And it worked finally:
[image]

Hope this can helps you.

Comment: was missing "/" in $BaseStorageUri = "https://****.blob.core.windows.net/****/"
 after modify this my code is working for S0 and S2 tier databases. Thanks @Leon

Comment: @Pavan You're welcome, I am glad it works now. I  think I didn't solve your issue directly.